# Replace data in Word by Excel VBA

Tags: excel, vba

I am using this code for my work but I got a problem, when I replace number it doesn't copy format. For example: In Excel 999.999 when replace in Word 999999. Could someone help me solving this ?

```
Sub test22()

Dim num_of_row As Long
    Dim num_of_column As Long
    Dim i As Long, j As Long
    Dim template As Object
    Dim t As Object
    Dim name As String


    num_of_column = 20

    num_of_row = ActiveSheet.Cells(Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Row - 1

    With CreateObject("word.application") ' late binding
        .Visible = False

        For i = 1 To num_of_row
            Set template = .documents.Open("D:\zzz LINH TINH\02. Test VBA\01. LRAMP\Template_KHQLMT.docx")
            Set t = template.Content
            For j = 1 To num_of_column
                t.Find.Execute _
                    FindText:=ActiveSheet.Cells(1, j).Value, _
                    ReplaceWith:=ActiveSheet.Cells(i + 1, j).Value, _
                    Replace:=wdReplaceAll
            Next
            template.SaveAs Filename:=ThisWorkbook.Path & Application.PathSeparator & i & "-KHQLMT " & ".docx"
        Next
        .Quit
    End With
    Set t = Nothing
    Set template = Nothing
End Sub
```

Comment: Try using `.Text` instead of `.Value`

Comment: Thank you so much. It works perfectly :)